# Use of Framelayout in Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: android, xml, android-framelayout, navigation-drawer

I have a doubt that, why you need to implement **FrameLayout widget** in the Navigation Drawer xml file?

Can any one clear my doubt...

Thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not *need* to use a `FrameLayout`.

However, *somehow*, you need to change your UI when the user clicks on an item in the drawer. One way to do that is to execute a `FragmentTransaction`, to change the mix of fragments in your UI. And a popular container for such dynamic fragments is a `FrameLayout`.